# using more than one find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I have just started learning Python and I need to scrape the number of hundreds of congress bills from https://www.congress.gov/bill/112th-congress. For example, I need to get to the H.R.6729 below. The structure of the HTML page to get to the text is:

BILL
    1.
    [H.R.6729](https://www.congress.gov/bill/112th-congress/house-bill/6729?r=1) — 112th Congress (2011-2012)

So it is hidden in a "li" and then in a "span". This is repeated for 100 congress bills in the webpage.

The code I have written is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.congress.gov/bill/112th-congress', headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
bills = soup.find_all("li", {"class" : "expanded"})
len(bills) # this is 100 as there are 100 bills in the page
for bill in bills:
    bill_number = bill.find_all("span", {"class":"result-heading"})
len(bills) # this is giving me 1
```

I reckon the problem is with the second find_all, why is the output just 1 element?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting `1` from because `soup` is not a consumable generator. I see 100 on both...

Comment: I'm sorry, the last line of code is wrong - I meant to write len(bill_number)

Comment: Your indentation is off and it needs to be in the loop. There should only be one bill number per bill.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation but it is always printing just bill 6630.

Comment: I highly suspect that you're using code that you're not posting... It's working exactly as expected... https://repl.it/@aalskdjh/ExcitedDismalFreesoftware

Comment: @asynts It was correct the whole time... [see](https://repl.it/@aalskdjh/ExcitedDismalFreesoftware)

Comment: Thank you @nicholishen, your code worked! Not sure what was wrong with mine, I suspect the use of find vs find_all. I owe you a coffe!

Answer (score 0):

you must transform

```
bill_number = bill.find_all("span", {"class":"result-heading"})
```

to

```
bill_number += bill.find_all("span", {"class":"result-heading"})
```